# how can I use router.all('path', Router Object') with Express?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to use router.all('path', RouterObject) for all method with right path to route to RouterObject.

```
const express = require("express");
const signup = require("./signup");

const router = express.Router();

router.all("/signup", signup);
router.use((_req, res) => res.status(404).send(`<h1>Page Not Found</h1>`));
```

./signup.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = require('../controllers/signup');

router.get('/', res.send("OK");

module.exports = router;
```

but It doesn't work as what I was expected.

It shows 404 Page, not 'hello', when I request with 'GET /signup'.

I want to use the signup module with same path name for '/signup' (not '/signup/something')

I tried `router.use("/signup", signup);`, It works, but I don't want pass the request with path like path '/signup/something' to the signup module.

How can I fix the problem using router.all() or is there any better way?

Comment: It shows 404 Page, not 'hello', when I request with 'GET /signup'.

=>It shows 404 Page, not 'OK', when I request with 'GET /signup'.

Comment: you mean to hanle all request like `app.get('/*', (req,res))` ?

Comment: nope, sorry for my bad question. I am not that good at English.
I mean to handle like app.all('/signup', Router Object for signup) like app.use('/signup', Router Object for signup). app.all() matches on exactly same path of the first argument, but, app.use() matches the every path name start with the first argument . I want to handle only exactly same path things. I dont want to handle every path that start with '/signup'.